# Declaring int variable with from...to range

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, properties

Can I declare an `int` variable with a *from...to* range, so that e.g. the `int count` can only have the value from `0` to `19`?

And when there should be a other value out of range added that just nothing happens, no exception, no new value or something else just ignore it.

I need this variable so often in one class e.g. when I need a value from a list, for the forward and backward buttons and in some methods. I don't want to make an `if`-clause or call a method every time.

Here is the code showing how I actually handle my problem, but I don't think that it's a good way to do this:

```
private void btnZurueckData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataFromGuiToObject(index);
    index--;
    if (index > -1)
    {
        resetGUI();
        setDataToGui(zeichnungen, index);
        btnVorData.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnZurueckData.IsEnabled = false;
        index++;
    }
}

private void btnVorData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataFromGuiToObject(index);
    index++;
    if (index < zeichnungen.Count)
    {
        resetGUI();
        setDataToGui(zeichnungen, index);
        btnZurueckData.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnVorData.IsEnabled = false;
        btnSpeichern.IsEnabled = true;
        index--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make it a property with the logic in it's `set {}` ?

Comment: Or (if your property is a DependencyProperty) use the `CoerceValueCallback` so your Bindings keep working.

Comment: A comment on the answers below, while they will work, I believe the intent isn't clear, i.e. someone reading `Count++` where `Count` is an int would *expect* it to increment .. I think it's better to either throw an exception if the values are out of bound as @viveknuna suggested, or implement your own class `BoundInt` with `TryIncrement` and `TryDecrement` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alex K already suggested you can write a Property and use the setter like this:

```
private int count;

public int Count
{
    get { return count; }
    set
    {
        count = (value >= 0 && value <= 19) ? value : count;
    }
}
```

This will check whether the new value of the variable is within the ranges that you set and if not, it will just remain at the old value. The initial value would be 0 as usual for a normal `int`;

If you are using Visual Studio type: *propfull* and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice. It will auto-generate a stereotypical property for you.

**EDIT:**

To answer the question from you comment. You can also call methods inside the property-setter. You could just make two methods to regulate which buttons have to be switched on or off:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // this is just to make the code work 
    List<int> zeichnungen = Enumerable.Range(0, 19).ToList();

    private int count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set
        {
            // if you are inside the bounds
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 19)
            {
                count = value;
                // enable the forward and backward button
                switchButtons();
            }
            else
            {   // you are out of bounds, so check at which side
                // and enable accordingly
                manageButtons(value);
            }
        }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In the `Click` events you can just increase or decrease the variable and leave the logic to the setter and your 2 custom methods

```
    private void btnVorData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Count++;
    }

    private void btnZurueckData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Count--;
    }

    // this method evaluates at which side you are
    private void manageButtons(int value)
    {
        if (value > zeichnungen.Count)
        {
            btnVorData.Enabled = false;
            btnSpeichern.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnZurueckData.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    // this just enables the forward and backward button and disables the save button
    private void switchButtons()
    {
        btnVorData.Enabled = true; 
        btnZurueckData.Enabled = true;
        btnSpeichern.Enabled = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: imo `count = Enumerable.Range(0,19).Contains(value) ? value : count;` is more elegant

Comment: @Innat3 it surely looks like it. But why, because it checks 19 times whether the value is present? Will it create an extra `IEnumarable<int>` with the length of 19 each time the `count` variable is set with a new value?

Comment: The OP said "And when there should be a other value out of range added that just nothing happens, [...], no new value or something else". Why would you believe that it should be 0? If of course right in the beginning you would initialise it with -1 than it *will* be 0, that is exactly what I said in my post "The initial value would be 0 as usual for a normal `int`"

Comment: how would it look like, if i want to enable the backwards button when i click forward and the other way round. So when im at the end the forward button should be disabled and the save button enabled. And the same thing when i go backwards.

Comment: did you declare the property inside the `Form` ?

Comment: I edited my question. am not sure whether I really understood your second question. Have a look

Comment: My project is in WPF but this isn´t really a problem. I have a custom ObservableCollection which contains a custom "zeichnung" object. I want to click through the Collection with the back and forward button and set the buttons then right in the GUI depending where i am in the Collection.

Comment: @Only3lue If you include such information like (WPF) into your question, also as a tag, it is highly probable that you get different answers. More fitting to the technology you are using.

Comment: @MongZhu yes you`re right. Its my mistake, but your answer helped me very much.

Comment: @Only3lue It is not a mistake of you. I just wanted to mention it, because solutions grow dependent on the context of the problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this validation in `set` property.

```
private int count;
public int Count
{
    set
    {
        if (value < 0 || value > 19) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(" Value should be between 0 to 19");
        this.count = value;
    }
    get { return this.count; }
}
```

You can throw exception if value is not in the required range or handle it in your way.

You can have the below condition also for same purpose.

```
if((value) * (19 - value) < 0)
        {

        }
```

Comment: `And when there should be a other value out of range added that just nothing happens, no exception [...]` I think you missed that part.

Comment: That's why he mentioned OP can handle it however he wants.

Comment: yes I have added this in my explanation, OP can handle accordingly. I want , let the OP try something by himself

Comment: how would it look like, if i want to enable the backwards button when i click forward and the other way round. So when im at the end the forward button should be disabled and the save button enabled. And the same thing when i go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function
Like

```
    public bool Enable(int value, int max = 19, int min = 0)
    {
        if()
        return (value >= min && value <= max);
    }

private void btnZurueckData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataFromGuiToObject(index);
    index--;
    if (Enable(index, zeichnungen.Count))
    {
        resetGUI();
        setDataToGui(zeichnungen, index);
        btnVorData.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnZurueckData.IsEnabled = false;
        index++;
    }
}

private void btnVorData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataFromGuiToObject(index);
    index++;
    if (Enable(index, zeichnungen.Count))
    {
        resetGUI();
        setDataToGui(zeichnungen, index);
        btnZurueckData.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnVorData.IsEnabled = false;
        btnSpeichern.IsEnabled = true;
        index--;
    }
}
```

this func will
1. make a call clearer
2. won't hide specific logic inside property

Answer (score -1):

My 2c...

```
public int Index
{
    get { return index; }
    set { index = Math.Min(19, Math.Max(0, value)); }
}
```

Comment: Regard the `no new value` in OPs question. If the value is greater than 19 or smaller than 0 he want's to ignore it and not place it on 19 or 0.

Comment: you are correct. I 'missed' the `no new value` part.